# No such option of selecting ubuntu after installing windows directly starting windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I just finished installing Windows 8. It's my first time with duel booting, so I accepted all the defaults and installed Win8. When the installation finished, I rebooted, but I am now taken directly to Windows with no option for the alternate OS. Windows Advanced Properties only lists Windows as an available OS. How do I enable Ubuntu to boot?

Comment: When you install Windows, it removes all options to access to other OS. Repair it following this http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu#6321

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same problem and resolved it using this guide:

https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/627767

Notes:

1. When he says main partition, he means your Ubuntu partition
2. You should follow step 8, even though it's said it's optional.
3. When using grub-install, notice that there's no number in
   /dev/sda
4. If you don't understand this sda1, sda2, sdb, notation, read up on
   it. It's very simple and helpful.

After this, GRUB will automatically detect both Windows and Ubuntu and you will be able to boot into either one next time you restart.